# Post Angular update(v14) website reload time increased compare to older(v5) version

Tags: angular, webpack-5

I am new in webpack5.Recently i upgraded my project that was running in **angular v5+ to angular v14+**, seems like all working fine.But found one observation - while loading application it's loading additional chunk file(**src_main_webapp_bootstrap_ts**).Seems like this file taking approx 2.31s of time to load.This file was not in oldest version. Hence website loading time is more every time on load/reload.

[image: src_main_webapp_bootstrap_ts]

[image: Load time Angular v5 vs Angular v14]

Comment: You're most likely not building in prod mode in v15.

Comment: It's prod build only.

Comment: I got some hints, so updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Updating my answer here, could be helpful for others.

After heading one day finally got solution. I found it was missconfigured some properties in production configurations in angular.json file. Basically sourceMap was set to true, hence loading/reloading time increased.

Earlier -

```
 "configurations": {
    "production": {
       "buildOptimizer": false,
       "optimization": false,
       "aot": false,
       "vendorChunk": true,
       "extractLicenses": false,
       "sourceMap": true,
}
 }
```

Updated with -

```
"configurations": {
   "production": {
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "optimization": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    }
  }
```